# How to connect to a server in Vagrant from Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, vagrant, virtualbox

I'm trying to run a local setup of our build server (Jenkins) using Vagrant on my Mac OSX running Yosemite.  I've been looking around and I've seen the requirement that the service must be listening to all interfaces (0.0.0.0 or ::::).

I have the Vagrant up and running and Jenkins running too.  The following is the output from `sudo netstat -tulpn`:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      965/sshd        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:57349           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      653/rpc.statd   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      591/rpcbind     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      965/sshd        
tcp6       0      0 :::57689                :::*                    LISTEN      2205/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::35586                :::*                    LISTEN      2205/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::33991                :::*                    LISTEN      653/rpc.statd   
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      591/rpcbind     
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      2205/java       
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*                           591/rpcbind     
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:60038           0.0.0.0:*                           653/rpc.statd   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6057            0.0.0.0:*                           496/dhclient    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:765             0.0.0.0:*                           591/rpcbind     
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:829           0.0.0.0:*                           653/rpc.statd   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           496/dhclient    
udp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                                591/rpcbind     
udp6       0      0 :::57046                :::*                                653/rpc.statd   
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                2205/java       
udp6       0      0 :::765                  :::*                                591/rpcbind     
udp6       0      0 :::52531                :::*                                496/dhclient    
udp6       0      0 :::33848                :::*                                2205/java
```

Jenkins is listening on port 8080 and is listening to `::::` (IPv6 all).  I can `curl localhost:8080` and get a response while inside the virtual machine but from my host computer I get the following:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: localhost:8080/
*   Trying ::1...
* connect to ::1 port 8080 failed: Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

I've also tried getting Java to bind the address using IPv4 so that the listen address is `0.0.0.0` however I get the same result.

The following is the output of my `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

From what I've read so far everything is setup as it should be but I must be doing something wrong.  Can you guys help me get this running?

If you need anymore information please let me know and I'll post it here.

Cheers,
Alexei Blue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to [forward port](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/forwarded_ports.html) from the guest to the host so add this in your Vagrantfile

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host: 8080
```

make sure to reload your VM by `vagrant reload` to take into effect and you will be able to access from your host

Comment: I feel so stupid because I came to the same conclusion about 2 seconds after posting the question and looking through the netstat output again.  So yes I had started Jenkins on port 8080 but I hadn't forwarded the port through to my host lol.  Thank you for the answer Frederic, I made the change and then ran vagrant reload --provision to ensure a clean build.